# Wordpress rewrites my link with custom URL scheme to http(s)

Tags: urls, links

I have a page that only users of my native iOS app will find, which should open the app. This works (on any other HTML page anyway) by linking to "myapp://path/inside/app".

Wordpress keeps "fixing" this to "https://path/inside/app", which doesn't work of course. I didn't find a setting to stop it from doing this.
Is this possible?

Comment: Where are you adding this link from? From the editor, the menu configuration page? My suggestion for this would be to use JavaScript to dynamically change the `href` of the link when somebody clicks it.

Comment: Adding the link from the editor.

Comment: Basically, I need something like this: https://sevenspark.com/tutorials/skype-uri-link-wordpress-menu but not for the skype:// protocol. Isn't editing the themes functions.php the wrong approach here as it gets overwritten on update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this plugin to address my problem: https://github.com/mehlkelm/Allow-My-URL-Schemes
At the moment it only works for my apps, pull requests welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that an HTML page is a single point of reference. Swift allows you to define that custom URL in your app ( https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-your-app-open-with-a-custom-url-scheme) but WordPress rewrites itself and all sub-pages, api etc. to the URL defined in the database options. So, short answer, you can't do that. If you were to set the URL of the WordPress site to myapp://whatever.com it would break. Do you have to use myapp:// ?

Comment: If I would be able to add a link to myapp://whatever nothing would break. A user without my app installed would just land on an unloadable page outside of my wordpress site.